# Cannot add child account to Microsoft Family group

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, gmail, microsoft-family-safety

My child has a Gmail account, and a Microsoft child account linked to the Gmail account, viz., the Gmail address is the Microsoft account username.  I am trying to add the child's Gmail account to my Microsoft family account. I go to the Microsoft Family Safety page, click on add family member, and enter the child's Gmail address to send an invitation. The child then logs into his Gmail account and clicks on "Accept" the invitation.  However, he then gets an error message along the lines of,

> You are already a member of a family.  You must exit the existing
> family.

and gets redirected to his own Microsoft Family Safety page.  But there is no option there for the child to exit his supposed family.  When I look at the child's Microsoft account page, it shows that he is the Organizer of his own single-member family. See attached screen.  He never purposefully created a family, and I started trying to add him to my Microsoft family concurrently with creating his Microsoft child account.

How can I add him to my Microsoft family?  Any help very much appreciated.

[image: Click for image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You probably should change the alias of the erroneous created Microsoft, freeing up the alias of the Google account, and create a new Microsoft account linked to the correct Family account. Might be able to delete the family, seems like a perfect situation, for Microsoft to provide assistance with.